# A JSON schema for W3C WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, jsonschema

The [Selenium WebDriver protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver) used for remotely controlling most modern web browsers is, nowadays, a [W3C Working Draft document](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver2/).

Is there a formalized [JSON schema](https://json-schema.org/) file for the WebDriver protocol that one can use to validate outgoing Selenium commands for data security purposes?

Comment: Why don't you ask the draft authors?

Comment: [Level 1 of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/) is more than a working draft; it’s a Recommendation. And, no, there isn’t an official JSON schema that conforms to the IETF recommendation.